# How to regenerate RSS feed URL like FeedBurner?

Tags: redirect, rss, feed, feedburner

I own several podcasts and faced the problem of changing rss feed on different podcast directories several times when I changed hosting.

I have been looking for a solution to this problem for a long time and at the moment the best option is to create a new RSS address via FeedBurner. And when the RSS feed of the podcast changes, I just need to change the incoming feed in the feedbuner. No need to change rss feed on podcast directories.

Help me create my RSS link on my domain like feedburner does (I'm not interested in the number of subscribers, just changing the link). For example, so that everything that will be distributed through supercast.libsyn.com/rss appears at the link feeds.mydomain.com/supercast.

I tried to redirect links through 301 redirect, but I'm not quite sure if this solution is correct.

Comment: 301 is permanent redirect, so probably not what you want: that would tell the podcast software to change its stored URL from your website to libsyn. (Although whether it actually does update is up to the software.)

Comment: You probably either want 302 or to fetch the RSS content from libsyn, cache it and re-serve it at the URL on your server from that link I'd think.

Comment: I decided to create my own feeds myself. The issue of regenerating existing feeds is relevant.